# calculating residue of $\frac{1}{z^4+1}$ efficiently

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, galois-theory

Calculate the residues of $\frac{1}{z^4+1}$ in terms of it's poles. What I've done is reduce $(x-x^3)(x-x^5)(x-x^7)$ mod $(x^4+1)$ to get $4x^3$. So we get $\frac{1}{4x^3}=-\frac{1}{4}x$.

Is there a more direct (faster) way to do this? Reducing $$(x-x^3)(x-x^5)(x-x^7)=-x^7+x^5+x^3-x^7-x^5+x^3=2(x^3-x^7)=2x^3(1-x^4)=4x^3$$ takes a minute...

Comment: Why not write this as $(z^2+i)(z^2-i),$ and go from there?

Comment: @AnotherUser no it doesn't

Comment: @Chickenmancer I don't see how I can get $-x/4$ faster in this way.

Comment: What is $x$ here?

Comment: @Ennar I'm looking at $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^4+1)$ so you may think of it as a 4th root of $-1$.

Comment: The residue's value *at $z$* (in the sense of complex analysis, at least) strongly depends on what the complex number $z$ is! The residues of $(z^4+1)^{-1}$ differ depending on which pole you calculate them at... so which one do you want?

Comment: @FShrike I calculated them for all poles, namely if $\zeta$ is the pole the residue is -$\zeta/4$. My question is how one could speed up the calculation. I want the residue at once for all poles (since I need all the residues).

Comment: @tatiana could you elaborate more on your methodology ? Why reducing that polynomial mod $x^4+1$ should give you information about the residues ? (the methods in the answers are more familiar to me...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using L'Hospital's Ruel, the residues are

$$\lim_{z\to z_n}\frac{z-z_n}{z^4+1}=\lim_{z\to z_n}\frac1{4z^3}=\frac1{4z_n^3}=-\frac14 z_n$$

where $z_n=e^{i(2n-1)\pi/4}$, for $n=1,2,3,4$, are the location of the $4$ simple poles of $\frac1{z^4+1}$.

Comment: Ah yeah, can't believe I've missed that! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: You are missing an equal sign I think

Comment: @Thomas Indeed.  I have corrected that omission.  Much appreciative of your alert.

Comment: @MarkViola Could you help by elaborating on how you understood that this is what the OP wanted, specifically?

Comment: @Chickenmancer I don't understand your question.  I read the posted question and provided a way forward that I thought was efficient.  Does that help clarify?

Answer (score 1):

Let's start from definition of residue. Given Laurent series of $f(z) = \sum_n a_n(z-c)^n$ around $c$, the residue is simply the coefficient $a_{-1}$. Now, let's say that $f$ has a pole at $c$ of order $n$, which means that $n$ is the smallest positive integer such that $(z-c)^nf(z)$ has removable singularity at $c$. In terms of Laurent series, we can write
\begin{align}
f(z) &= a_{-n}(z-c)^{-n} +a_{-n+1}(z-c)^{-n+1}+\ldots+ a_{-1}(z-c)^{-1} + a_0 + \ldots\\
(z-c)^nf(z) &= a_{-n}+a_{-n+1}(z-c)+\ldots+a_{-1}(z-c)^{n-1}+a_0(z-c)^n+\ldots
\end{align}
What we now want to do is kill all the summands up to $a_{-1}(z-c)^{n-1}$ and since they are polynomials of degree lesser than $n-1$ we can differentiate the above expression $n-1$ times to get

$$\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}( (z-c)^nf(z) ) = a_{-1}(n-1)! + \text{some powers of }(z-c)$$ so the right hand side evaluated at $z = c$ gives us $(n-1)!a_{-1}$. So, we get the following formula:

$$a_{-1} = \frac 1{(n-1)!}\lim_{z\to c}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}( (z-c)^nf(z) ).$$ So, in case of a simple pole, we get the residue $$\operatorname{Res}(f,c) = \lim_{z\to c}(z-c)f(z).$$ At this point we take out our handbook of magical trickery and do the following. Assume that $f = g/h$ where $g$ and $h$ are holomorphic at $c$ , $h(c) = 0$ and $h'(c)\neq 0$. What you can do is now use l'Hospital's rule to calculate the limit $$\lim_{z\to c} \frac{(z-c)g(z)}{h(z)} = \frac{g(c)}{h'(c)},$$ and that will give us our residue.

I'll show how it works in your example. Choose $c$ such that $c^2 = i$. Since $z^4+1$ has $4$ distinct roots, we know this will be a simple pole of $f(z)=1/(z^4+1)$. Write $$f(z) = \frac{1/(z^2+i)}{z^2-i}$$ and define $g(z) = 1/(z^2+i)$, $h(z) = z^2-i$. Note that $g$ and $h$ are holomorphic at $c$, $h(c) = 0$ and $h'(c)\neq 0$. Now,
$$\operatorname{Res}(f,c) = \lim_{z\to c}(z-c)f(z) = \frac{g(c)}{h'(c)} = \frac{1/(2i)}{2c} = \frac 1{4ic}.$$